# Expo cannot auto import React-native on Visual studio code in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, visual-studio-code, expo

I just start to learn the react-native with Expo SDK.
I follow the [official tutorial](https://docs.expo.io/get-started/installation/) to init managed Typescript template.
[image]

And I found that I can only import unique React-native component.
[image]

Not the React-native component which has same name across Dom, React.
[image]

I saw the node-modules already have the Types but not know why the auto-import not work.

This is what vscode try to find but not go through the React-native type definition.
[image]

But React-native types has the type definition.
[image]

If I import the Text manually from the React-native, it can get the correct definition.

`import { Image, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';`
[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Silly question, but are you sure you're importing Text from react-native and not react?

Comment: Yes, if I import it manually from React-native, if I click the go the definition, it shows the React-native Text definition.